# Open SpecFlow test from Text Explorer goes to the feature class file not the feature file

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nunit, specflow

I've seen people talk about a similar issue when using Re-Sharper, but I am not using Re-Sharper.

When I double click (or press F12) on a SpecFlow test within Test Explorer, it used to take me to the test within a .feature file, however it has now started taking me to the class file (.feature.cs), is there a setting or something I could have accidentally set?

I have deleted all of the SpecFlow related files in my temp directory, I know that's usually the fix for when steps aren't mapping properly so thought i'd give it a go

project packages installed;
SpecFlow v2.2.1 (latest as of writing)
SpecFlow.NUnit v2.2.1 (Latest as of writing)

Im using the latest version of VS2017
Extension: SpecFlow for Visual Studio 2017 v2017.1.6 (latest as of writing)

Any ideas on how to fix this annoying issue?

Comment: Please file an issue on https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow
Could be that the code generation has a problem.

Comment: Issue created https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/990

Comment: There are a few work around's that work for me and a few others in the git hub issue I created (https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/990) some people are still seeing the problem after trying the work around's though.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed in VS17 version 15.8.